# What happen if I use reduceByKey or groupByKey one large datasets having only two keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm using spark to process my data. I have paired RDD that is distributed on multiple executors. The data size is 10tb and the no of partitions are 4000. The total no of executors are 100 and the memory on every executor is 20GB.

So the size of every partition will be around 128mb.

i.e

```
pairedRDD = sc.textFile("myhost:9000/data/largedataset.txt", 4000);
resultRdd = pairedRDD.reduceByKey(lambda (x, y) : (x + y));
```

The data in the file is like,

```
1 Apple
1 Apple
2 Mango
1 Apple
3 Banana
```

We have only 3 keys. So all the related keys will move to same partition. As we have one partition size 512mb and we have 4000 partition, it will cause any OOM error or it will execute without any error.

If it will execute without any error then how Spark is handling the size of data internally?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of Spark will heavily depend on what you choose:  `reduceByKey` or `groupByKey`.

- `GroupByKey` will bring all data in one partition (using shuffling) and in your case it will cause OOM (Out Of Memory).
- `ReduceByKey` will first do logic on each executor and then do bring the resulted values on one executor.

Comment: So reduceByKey will not cause OOM while groupByKey can?

Comment: yes. the best practices in spark say that it is better to avoid groupByKey
https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Comment: but in my case it will not make much difference as the result after the reduceByKey or groupByKey will be like,
1 (AppleAppleAppleAppleApple)
2 (MangoMangoMangoMango)

So reduceByKey can also cause OOM?

Comment: @Pirate: In that case, an OOM would be highly probable.

Comment: but if we see any wide transformation in spark, they do shuffle and brought back same keys to one partition. So if i join two datasets then again it will be OOM? and if this is the case the Spark will fail with big data?